# can I localize strings directly in an iOS storyboard without using code?

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

I have a really simple Startscreen in the storyboard with a UILabel and a Button. No classfiles are yet needed and would like to avoid having two extra files just for setting one UILabel in viewdidload.

Is there a way to set the Label directly in the storyboard? Like for example select the UILabel and write in the title tab NSLocalizedString(@"startlabel", nil) ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create outlets for `UILabel` and `UIButton` and then programatically change titles:

```
myLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"startlabel", "start label");
[myButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"startButton", "start button") forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

and don't forget to create `Localizable.strings` files where you can specify your translations

Comment: like I said I would like to avoid doing it programatically, but if there isn't another way i will have to.

Comment: Unfortunately there are only two ways of doing this: create separate storyboards or programatically set titles through NSLocalizedString. Hope it answered your question

Comment: that definitely does. Thank you